Is there another for-loop-like option for such a function to consider two consecutive elements in an array in Javascript?
My codes looks like this now, and there is the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML') appeared in the console log, providing the line number as the first line of the if functions, when I click the button. I'd like to know if a for loop, or a forEach function, or any other options can show the text and the border as written in the if functions in the codes now?


const relationships = document.getElementById('relationships');
const frames = document.getElementById('frames');
const reds = document.getElementById('reds');
const time = document.getElementById('time');
const day = document.getElementById('day');
const month = document.getElementById('month');
const yr = document.getElementById('yr');
const underFrames = document.getElementById('underFrames');
const underRlps = document.getElementById('underRlps');
const btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

const rlps = [time, day, month, yr];

window.onload = (event) => {
  frames.style.display = "none";
  underFrames.style.display = "none";
  relationships.style.display = "none";
  underRlps.style.display = "none";
};

btn.addEventListener("click", function show() {
  frames.style.display = "table-row";
  underFrames.style.display = "table-row";
  relationships.style.display = "table-row";
  underRlps.style.display = "table-row";

  for (let a = 0; a < rlps.length; a++) {
    if (rlps[a].innerHTML == "Crimson" && rlps[a + 1].innerHTML == "Scarlet") {
      frames.cells[a].style.borderLeft = "1px inset black";
      frames.cells[a].style.borderRight = "1px inset black";
      frames.cells[a].style.borderTop = "1px inset black";
      relationships.cells[a].innerHTML += "Good";
    } else if (rlps[a].innerHTML == "Scarlet" && rlps[a + 1].innerHTML == "Red") {
      frames.cells[a].style.borderLeft = "1px inset black";
      frames.cells[a].style.borderRight = "1px inset black";
      frames.cells[a].style.borderTop = "1px inset black";
      relationships.cells[a].innerHTML += "Bad";
    } else if (rlps[a].innerHTML == "Red" && rlps[a + 1}.innerHTML == "Crimson") {
      underFrames.cells[a].style.borderLeft = "1px inset black";
      underFrames.cells[a].style.borderRight = "1px inset black";
      underFrames.cells[a].style.borderBottom = "1px inset black";
      underRlps.cells[a].innerHTML += "Good";
    }
  }
});
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="relationships">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="frames">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="reds">
        <td id="time">Rose</td>
        <td id="day">Crimson</td>
        <td id="month">Scarlet</td>
        <td id="yr">Red</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="underFrames">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="underRlps">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button">Show</button>
</div>




Looks like stopping the loop at rlps.length - 1 is a possible solution. You're getting the undefined error at the last element.

maybe start from the start. I got no idea what you're actually trying to do and your question is rather confusing. Why do think you need a for loop? What is the goal of the script? Always start at the very beginning so that we can understand you project. As of now I need to read you code which barely makes any sense to get a guess what you're trying.

The problem as I see is in checking rlps[a + 1].innerHTML when cycle is on the last element. Consider adding another condition in if statements, e.g. if (rlps[a].innerHTML == "Crimson" && rlps[a + 1] && rlps[a + 1].innerHTML == "Scarlet") {

@Pointy Looks like a break at rlps.length - 1 would be the solution.
